# Grab the associated date of jql date functions with jira rest api? or using python?

Tags: python, python-datetime

Is there an easy way or even any *way* to go about doing this. Let's say I have startOfWeek and startOfWeek(-1)
is there a way to grab the dates associated with this?

I've tried querying on issues but the issues exist within the range of sow --> sow(-1) so it technically would not be the correct date and it's probably near impossible to determine the startOfTheWeek given no relevant date.

Dates for issues are in the format of YYYY:MM:DD, no reference to day of the week. Is there possibly a way I could feed a date in to python and return the date of the start of that week?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If JIRA doesn't provide something out of the box, there's quite a good chance it can be scripted, but it's not really clear to me what you need.

Comment: I wanted to get the date of the beginning of the week given a day
so for 7/22/2016 today, I wanted to grab sunday or 7/17/2016. But the issue was figuring out how to figure out what day of the week I'm at using python, and then counting back to grab the beginning of the week. It looks like the datetime module supports this, its a little hacky, so I won't post it as an answer yet.

Comment: Ok, that's a pure python question then.

Comment: yeah my bad, I had no idea if the jira-rest-api had a way to do that, I'll remove the tag then.